# How do you properly dispose of hexane and cyclohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry

How do you properly dispose of hexane and cyclohexane?

Comment: It is a rather short question, the problem is that it offers very little information about what the person is asking. The safe and legal disposal of "chemicals" is not a trivial matter. I will have a go at answering in the near future.

Comment: For amounts common for a small-scale lab it is safe to let it evaporate into atmosphere or burn it.  For industrial scales you could run into legal matters and should consult local law.

Comment: @permeakra - in my labs, I am prohibited from intentionally letting waste evaporate to dispose of it, regardless of quantity. Check and follow all applicable procedures and local, regional, and country laws.

Answer (score 2):

Hexane and cyclohexane waste is hazardous waste, the law on the disposal of waste will vary from one part of the world to another. From a UK point of view, you need to transfer the waste to a licensed waste contractor. The producer of waste has a responsibility to make sure that they only use a licensed waste contractor rather than some fly by night criminal who would dump it in a graveyard, play park or commit some other waste related crimes.

A common method in the UK and other places to dispose of solvent waste is to use it as fuel for the production of cement, or in other places where some liquid fuel is needed to do things like start up a furnace. I know that incineration plants oftein use some liquid fuel to start a furnace before changing over to using domsetic rubbish (MSW) as the fuel.

Hexane and cyclohexane might be a bit too flammable to use in some applications, but I am sure that if care is taken then they could be used as industrial fuels.

If the waste is mainly one solvent or if the final user does not care too much about the purity of their solvent (consider how much heptane you would tolerate in your toluene) then one option is to distill the solvent waste and then to recycle the solvent. The problem with this is that if you have a waste which is 95 % hexane and 5 % involatile stuff then you will have to sacrifice some hexane to avoid the still pot becoming filled with some involatile residual which you have to then use hexane (or another solvent) to wash out.

If the solvent waste has some very horrible impurity in it, such as imagine PCBs from a process in which old transformers casings have been washed out. Then the hexane waste will have to go to a high temperture incinerator which is optimised for the destruction of the PCBs rather than energy recovery. Many incinerators are designed to recover energy from the burning process, a MSW incinerator will form some dioxin but the amount will be very low as the temperture and the chemistry of the plant is chosen such that very little is formed, what is formed is normally filtered.

On the otherhand if a plant was to be fed with things like PCBs (polychlorobiphenyls) and unwanted 2,4,5-T from the 1970s which contained dioxin then I think more effort would have to be made to destroy the existing dioxin and also prevent the formation of new dioxin. This could well reduce the amount of energy recovered per ton of waste. For example you would be able to get some reduction in the net dioxin production by adding an afterburner to the incinerator. But the afterburner will require a supply of fuel. Even if you preheat the air going into the afterburner with heat from the air leaving the afterburner, there will be some fuel needed to operate the afterburner. As a result the energy ecconomy of the site will become worse.